# NodeJS - Request a page with later loaded info

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, request, web-crawler

I'm making a web-crawler with nodeJS, it's working, it calls the page, I use cheerio to convert to JQuery, and call the tags.

And now I'm trying to call the comments of the page, but the problem is, the tag that I want is loaded after some seconds from an Ajax GET request. And the request-promise that I made can't find this specific tag, because it loads later.

There is some way that I can find that tag loaded?

Code :

```
/* Requires */
var rp = require('request-promise');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

//Page to crawl

var pageToVisit = "http://pagetoVisit.com/page-with-comments.html";
console.log("Visiting "+pageToVisit);


var options = {
    uri: pageToVisit,
    transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
    },
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    simple: false
};

rp(options)
    .then(function ($) {
        console.log($('.CommentsTag').text());
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // Crawling failed...
    });
```

Comment: extract the ajax url, then do a second request. However that requires a lot of debugging, which probably wont fit the scope of an answer :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that you will be able to do that using 'cheerio'. It parses an HTML DOM but for all intents and purposes, it is not a web browser, so it will not execute scripts on the page. You will need to use something like CasperJS (powered by PhantomJS) to render the page to allow you to wait for content to load via scripts.

[CasperJS waitForSelector](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector)

EDIT: In the cheerio documentation.

> Cheerio is not a web browser
>
> Cheerio parses markup and provides an API for traversing/manipulating the resulting data structure. It does not interpret the result as a web browser does. Specifically, it does not produce a visual rendering, apply CSS, load external resources, or execute JavaScript. If your use case requires any of this functionality, you should consider projects like PhantomJS or JSDom.

Comment: That actually worked, I used PhantomJs with CasperJS, Called the page and the comments were shown. Thanks